# How to input "=" in table cell in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I hope to know how to input "=" in the table cell as the first char?

If I put "=" as the first char, it always call the formula function.

Answer (score 2):

Escape it with a `'`. Just like Excel...